# How to set Button width to column width in Page Builder

Tags: magento2, grid, page-builder

[image]
**Explanation**

I have a 3 by 2 grid with equal wide columns on my starting page which I created with Page Builder. In each of the cells there is a picture and a button. In different browser sizes the images always use the full width of the column. The buttons however differ from that behaviour. There are certain browser sizes when the button is narrower than the picture which is a pain for the eye.

- The system is Magent Commerce, ver. 2.4.2-p2
- I've reproduced this with both Google Chrome and Firefox

**My question:**

How can I configure the buttons to always use the full width of the column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: We need to add "**min-width: 100%**" to the button-item in CSS.
Now our solution partner needs to add the min-width to the style sheets. Unfortunately I can not do this in page builder.

[image]

**Update 20211013:**
In the mean time I found a more elegant way to solve the problem in page builder:
To get the desired layout and element behavior I need only align appearance attribute of Button element with the value "Stacked"
[image: screenshot of button settings]